# Responsibility of a Factory

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, single-responsibility, factory

I am trying to refactor a huge chunk of our software, and it requires to set up a factory. However, I am not sure where lies its responsibility.

(PS: The code below is shown simply as an illustration and may not be perfectly designed, please do not unleash hell on it :()

---

Should the factory only return the correct instance to its parent ?

```
public class UsingFactory {
      public String getToken(ModelEnum parameter)    {
          Tokenizer tokenizer = MyFactory.getTokenizer(parameter);
          return tokenizer.getToken();
      }
}

public static class MyFactory    {
      public Tokenizer getTokenizer(ModelEnum parameter)   {
            // return whatever Tokenizer needed
      }
}
```

Or could it already return a token ?

```
public class UsingFactory {
      public String getToken(ModelEnum parameter)    {
          return MyFactory.getToken(parameter);
      }
}

public static class MyFactory    {
      public String getToken(ModelEnum parameter)   {
            Tokenizer tokenizer = getTokenizer(parameter);
            return tokenizer.getToken();
      }
}
```

I can't see whether of them is the best, even if the first option seems, to me, to apply better to SRP. Could this factory be in charge of returning a `String` token directly, or should it first return the instance of the correct `Tokenizer` class ?

Comment: It depends. What are you "trying" to construct? Tokenizers? Tokens? Factories are meant to play the role of constructors. May some say that the 2nd option is doing something more beyond construction (tokenization) what could be interpreted as a violation of the Factory's single responsibility. Even if the factory is meant to generate "tokens". Would not it be an "utility" class rather than a factory?

Comment: Well, indeed if the factory is meant to generate tokens and not Tokenizers, it would not be a factory anymore ... That makes sense. Didn't see it that way.

Comment: It sounds like you might need a `TokenRepository` rather than a `TokenFactory` or `TokenizerFactory`.  `TokenRepository.findBy(parameter)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips that could help you out to decide.

1. Decide what you want the Factory to produce: *tokens* or *tokenizers*.
2. Then change the name *MyFactory* to something more descriptive. *TokenFactory* or *TokenizerFactory* (based on your previous decision).

Still doubtful? *Keep it simple*. Segregate concerns.

As you said, option #1 is the more canonical implementation of a factory of the two. So far so good. While option #2; well, some may argue that it violates the factory's main responsibility. However, [as @Neil's answer says](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/388082/222996), it depends on what you really want the factory to produce (hence the tips). Right now is open to interpretation.

If I'm allowed to suggest, if I had to choose, I would start by breaking the ambiguity changing the factory's name to *TokenizerFactory*. Then, I would go option #1 because its logic remains true the definition of a factory. [The second is something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Additionally, to easier the tokens retrieving, I would do it from a different component. Say, a utility class (to mention any).

```java
public static class TokenUtils{
   private TokenUtils(){}
   public static final String retrieveToken(ModelEnum parameter){
      return new MyTokenizersFactory().getTokenizer(parameter).getToken();
   }
}
```

Or as a regular class

```java
public class ModelEnumTokenRetriever implements TokenRetriever<ModelEnum> {
   private final ModelEnumTokenizersFactory tokenizerFactory;
   private ModelEnumTokenRetriever(ModelEnumTokenizersFactory tokenizerFactory){
      //assert tokenizerFactory is not null
      //then
      this.tokenizerFactory = tokenizerFactory;
   }
   public static final String retrieveToken(ModelEnum parameter){
      return new tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(parameter).getToken();
   }
}
```

This way, both responsibilities, *how to obtain tokenizers* and *how to obtain tokens* are segregated.

The segregation allows us to tie the rest of the source code to one or another based on the needs.

---

***Note***: Note that KIS is not always synonym of less code. Usually, good practices lead us to write more code, but easier to understand or easier to read. Mine is one possible approach of the many. We have to find the approach that best adapts to our needs

Answer (score 1):

So what you're asking is should you write a `TokenFactory` or a `TokenizerFactory`?  Both are ultimately being used for the scope of producing tokens, but one would require an additional step.

Is that a bad thing?  No, it entirely depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Does `Tokenizer` do something other than provide a token?  If so, what?  The reason I ask is because if it has other functionality, there is a certain logic towards having a `TokenizerFactory`, since you're effectively modularizing the creation of `Tokenizer` instances throughout your program, not only in the place where you need tokens.

If on the other hand, you *only* need to create tokens, then I believe that what you need is a `TokenFactory`, and not a `TokenizerFactory` (I humbly disagree with Laiv's answer here in this specific instance that you'd necessarily need an additional class).  The factory becomes slightly more complex, but it removes what would otherwise be an unnecessary step towards retrieving the token.  And in the general case, an overly complicated means of creating a token might merit its own class, but I would argue that this is not your case.

Please note that this solution should not be considered if you think this may change in the future, but it would seem to me that your `Tokenizer` class is not likely going to do anything other than return tokens.

Comment: Curiously I agree with your answer. Depending on *what you need to instantiate* one is more convenient than the other. I tried to avoid guessing about the OP's real intentions or needs and I took the "middle way".

Comment: @Laiv It depends on context of course, so I tried to include both possibilities.  Honestly I think we're both right in different ways.

Comment: I  have edited my answer to let it open to possibilities as you do because I think you are right. I gave some tips to allow the OP to make his/her own reasoning and choice. I kept the example, just to illustrate a possible approach (the one I would go for).

Answer (score 0):

A Factory of any kind should only create an instance of an object.
The method is often called `Create` to make that obvious.

I would suggest to use the first example.

Please consider also WHY you are using a factory in general.
Considering you are refactoring a huge code base.

In your example using a factory does not make sense at all.
It actually adds a dependency to `MyFactory` to `UsingFactory`.
Now `UsingFactory`depends on `Tokenizer` AND `MyFactory`.
When you use `new Tokenizer()` directly you will have one dependency less.

Be aware! Depending on concrete classes is bad practice in general, but this is off topic now.